# How to expand log error level in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, apache-spark, airflow, apache-beam

I'm encountering an issue while running an Apache Beam DAG as part of an ETL process in Apache Spark, orchestrated by Apache Airflow, and executed on AWS. When I run the DAG, I'm getting the following error in the log:

```
23/09/29 11:02:45 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error encoding value: null
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.beamExceptionFrom(SparkPipelineResult.java:73)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(SparkPipelineResult.java:104)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(SparkPipelineResult.java:92)
    at com.evalua.etl.Etl.main(Etl.java:315)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:742)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error encoding value: null
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.coders.CoderHelpers.toByteArray(CoderHelpers.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.GroupNonMergingWindowsFunctions.lambda$groupByKeyInGlobalWindow$ca0fe113$1(GroupNonMergingWindowsFunctions.java:276)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$.$anonfun$pairFunToScalaFun$1(JavaPairRDD.scala:1073)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1516)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null Integer
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.VarIntCoder.encode(VarIntCoder.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.VarIntCoder.encode(VarIntCoder.java:33)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.coders.CoderHelpers.toByteArray(CoderHelpers.java:58)
    ... 14 more
```

I would like to understand more about the origin of this error and obtain detailed information about the exceptions that appear under "Caused by" after the line "... 14 more." How can I expand the log error so I can see those "14 more" lines?

Thank you for your assistance!

I have tried little since I do not know how to expand the log.

I expect to see the full log error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null Integer
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.VarIntCoder.encode(VarIntCoder.java:49)` indicates your data has the invalid integer.

Comment: Hi @XQHu, thanks for your reply. I am trying to locate where is the invalid integer, but I can't since the error log does not show more info :)

Comment: My suggestion is to try this with DirectRunner if possible and print elements, or in your transform, try to add some checks for the elements.